# Change attributes on folder - Different name on every computer

Tags: command-line

I need to run a command on nearly 100 computers, and want a better way to do it.

```
attrib +s +r FolderName_100
```

The folder it resides:  `C:\Temp\LocalCache\`

The trick is that the FolderName_100 is different on every computer. The number changes.
There is an environment variable that can be used to ID that number `Station_ID`.

I tried running the command with a wildcard `attrib +s +r FolderName_*` It failed.

I'm not good with scripting, but I can edit others' scripts to make them work for me.
I just haven't found anything out there for this specific task.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried PsExec?   ....   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough.  Do you want the folder itself only?  If so, .. something like "attrib /D +s +r C:\Temp\LocalCache\FolderName_%Station_ID%\" ? If you combine this with @John suggestion, you don't even need to leave your chair.

Comment: @john The remote running of the script isn't a problem. Its the script itself that I cannot get to work.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Yes, the folder itself, and anything inside of it.  Running commands remotely isn't a problem. I can use PDQ to deploy it, or we can run them from MeshCentral.   Getting the command to work is the hard part.     I'll attempt your suggestion to see if it throws any errors.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I had to remove the last \ but this command did work.  I also had to run it with a /s because /d required it???  It just allows for all files to be included, so it works exactly how I needed it. Thank you!